# minispy - Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file

Tags: drivers, certificate, digital-signature, windows-server-2016

I have built the Microsoft sample [minispy minifilter](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/minispy) with no issue. I made sure that since I am using 64-bit, I have also compiled in x64 on my Visual Studio. Tried both Debug and Release. Hence in terms of coding, it should be correctly done, hence this is not a programming question.

A digital certificate is required. Here is a screen shot to show that it was correctly installed:
[Click here for screen shot of digital certificate status being OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljwqy.png)

I later installed minispy using the .inf file (.sys and .exe files in the same folder as .inf, got this from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0bb34219-3e94-41fd-89e7-92670eedac51/minispy?forum=wdk)). The first problem (and I suspect it is the main problem) then shows in this screen shot:
[Click here for screen shot of digitally unsigned driver error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljwqy.png)

If you are not able to see the screen shot, it says:

> A digitally signed driver is required
>   Minispy Filter Driver
>   Windows (R) Win 7 DDK provider
>   Windows blocked the installation of a digitally unsigned driver. Uninstall the program or device that uses the driver and check the publisher's website for a digitally signed version of the driver.

This is despite having the certificate already properly installed as shown above. Note that I am using Administrator privileges. I am also running on an AWS EC2 instance, in which I cannot reboot and hit F8 to disable digital signature, and check if this is a signed driver issue (as explained here: [Windows cannot verify the digital signature for the drivers required for this device](https://superuser.com/questions/99539/windows-cannot-verify-the-digital-signature-for-the-drivers-required-for-this-de)). If it helps to know, my machine is running on Windows Server 2016.

When I had come to the part about loading the service, here is what I saw on the console after I entered the following command line:

```
fltmc load minispy
```

> Load failed with error: 0x80070241
>   Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source.

```
net start minispy
```

> System error 577 has occurred.
>   Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source.

I've tried several times and having researched for a couple of hours - can't seem to find specific steps in installing and setting up minispy, I wonder why. And while my issue is specific to the minispy minifilter, I think this is really more about the system and about installing drivers. Would really appreciate any help on where I might have gone wrong, and how I may resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find a solution so the workaround I did was to disable the following:

1. Program Compatibility Assistant: https://winhelp.co/knowledge-base/windows-10-disable-program-compatibility-assistant-2/
2. Driver signature enforcement: https://windowsreport.com/driver-signature-enforcement-windows-10/ (I haven't tried this again on an AWS EC2 instance, but on my own laptop instead)

Like I said, it is a workaround. If anyone has a real solution, I'd be most delighted to hear how.

After this, I am now able to install the minispy.inf and run minispy.exe.